Dynamically creating a reusable, editable, and savable clipping path with bezierCurveTo() for image masking in canvas
I want to dynamically create, with mouse, savable, reusable and editable bezier curve paths comprising moveable points and handles just like the pen tool allows in Photoshop. I would use these for masking parts of an image for composite layering. I'm looking for a lightweight vanilla javascript solution that I can work with, expand, and learn from.
Because of my current very little knowledge of HTML5 canvas applications, I could only programmatically supply clipping path values via bezierCurveTo() for masking an image through an irregular shape, but I am looking for a solution that allows me to dynamically draw, edit, reuse, and save clipping paths for image mask creation just like the pen tool in Photoshop provides. Here is the programmatical version I tried so far in this fiddle:
Note: Using img.onload for example only.
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {

// Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
ctx.save();

var xoff = 10; //  pixel x-offset of handle (when moved dynamically)
var yoff = 10; //  pixel y-offset of handle (when moved dynamically)
    
// This is the irregular shape
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(29 + xoff, 55 + yoff);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(18 + xoff, 37 + yoff, 39 + xoff, 16 + yoff, 48 + xoff, 28 + yoff);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(82 + xoff, 75 + yoff, 162 + xoff, 5 + yoff, 155 + xoff, 18 + yoff);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(128 + xoff, 73 + yoff, 154 + xoff, 123 + yoff, 167 + xoff, 131 + yoff);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(186 + xoff, 143 + yoff, 111 + xoff, 145 + yoff, 96 + xoff, 148 + yoff);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(81 + xoff, 151 + yoff, 24 + xoff, 154 + yoff, 34 + xoff, 135 + yoff);
  
ctx.closePath();

// Clip to the current path
ctx.clip();
    
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    
// Undo the clipping
ctx.restore();
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";

In attempting to solve my problem, I analyzed pertinent code made freely available in this post, but can't quite grasp (still trying) on how to conjugate only what is strictly needed for implementing the dynamic aspect of drawing clipping paths with bezierCurveTo().
Lastly, I want to implement the clipping path functionality into this freely available javascript-canvas-image-mask application. I would add a pen tool option right over the paint brush tool option that is already implemented in that code. Therefore, the javascript-canvas-image-mask application will be the UI/UX template used to provide both pen and paint brush tools for image masking.
So any working samples, hints or suggestions you want to offer me should be applicable to the javascript-canvas-image-mask application mentioned in the above link. Lean and simple is best - I'm not interested in adopting existing frameworks because they usually provide many more functionality than I actually need.
Thank you for your guidance, can't wait to get my hands more dirty on this one.

It's pretty much going to be "replace those hardcoded values with values stored "somewhere else" and update your drawing/clipping region every time those change". That's more of a general programming thing than specific to this code: Create a path class that consists of on-curve points and controls points, with event listening so that users can manipulate those points, and update events so that your canvas/clipping code can "redo itself" when the path changes. But note that SO is not a "please write code for me" service: you're going to have to do the (re)searching for implementations yourself

(And then when you get stuck on a specific part of implementing your idea, that's the appropriate time to ask SO for help, because you'll be able to show code and explain what you expected that code to do, and what it's doing instead)

@Mike Hello, and thanks for reply. Yes, know how things work at SO, just giving most details as possible for coders with more knowledge to suggest how I should put things together. I see you provide "A Primer on Bézier Curves", so I'll be looking at that carefully in order to better implement sought design.

You want an editable bezier curve ...
but then you mention pen tool like Photoshop, that is no longer a bezier curve.
In your code there is no effort to make anything editable, to make something user editable I expected to see some event listeners to get some input from the user...
You have many questions in one post, you have to break your problem down to very specific issues, for example I'm just going to focus on editing a bezier curve see my sample code below:


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let points = [{x:30, y:60}, {x:100, y:100}, {x:200, y:50}, {x:300, y:100}]
let selected = -1;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(points[1].x, points[1].y, points[2].x, points[2].y, points[3].x, points[3].y);
    ctx.stroke();

    for (const point of points) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        const dist = Math.hypot(points[i].x - mouseX, points[i].y - mouseY);
        if (dist < 6) { // radius for control point
            selected = i;
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
            break;
        }
    }
});

function onMouseMove(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    points[selected].x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    points[selected].y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    draw();
}

function onMouseUp() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    selected = -1;
}


draw();
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="180"></canvas>



